# Unable to sink messages from a Kafka consumer to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

i am able to read messages from a kafka topic using kafka-console-consumer

```
/bin/kafka-console-consumer --topic Test --consumer.config 
/etc/kafka/consumer.properties --from-beginning --bootstrap-server 
ip1:9095,ip2:9095,ip3:9095
```

but unable to sink these messages to a table in postgres using jdbc-sink-connector

```
/bin/connect-standalone /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro- 
standalone.properties /etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/psql.properties
```

The consumer config loaded through this command is not picking the right group.id and sasl verfication that i am using. Is there a way to pass the same consumer configuration values in this code as well?

Connector properties

```
name=postgres-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=3
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://IP:5432/db? 
user=postgres&password=postgres
insert.mode=upsert
pk.mode=record_value
table.name.format=kafka_users
auto.create=true
auto.evolve=true
topics=Test
```

Comment: Please add your connector properties to the question

Comment: @cricket_007 - added the connector properties

Comment: And the connect-avro-standalone file? And your consumer properties file?